# When should I update the UI with React.js state vs just CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, state, reactjs

I am recreating an input example from this [site](http://blog.circleci.com/adaptive-placeholders/). When you click inside the input the label, which was acting as placeholder, moves up and acts as a label. This action is done in CSS. The data of the form is not being updated, but the UI is changing, does this count as a change in state? Should the change in CSS stay as just CSS, or should it be triggered by something in the React component?

There is an example, with out React at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/easilyBaffled/UCpm5/9/).

**JS:**

```
function generate_adaptive_text_input(initial, focused){
    var adaptive_placeholder_input_container = $("<div />", {
        class: 'adaptive_placeholder_input_container'
    });
        var adaptive_placeholder_input = $("<input />",{
            type: 'text',
            required: '',
            class: 'adaptive_text_input'
        });
        var adaptive_placeholder_label = $("<label />",{
            alt: initial,
            placeholder: focused,
            class: 'adaptive_placeholder'
        });
        adaptive_placeholder_input_container.append(adaptive_placeholder_input);
        adaptive_placeholder_input_container.append(adaptive_placeholder_label);
    return adaptive_placeholder_input_container;
}

function generate_form(){
    var form = $('<form />');
        var first_example = generate_adaptive_text_input('Placeholder', 'Active Placeholder');
        var second_example = generate_adaptive_text_input('Off', 'On');


        $(form).append(first_example);
        $(form).append(second_example);
    return form;
}    

function generate_page(){
    var form = generate_form();
    $('body').append(form);
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.adaptive_placeholder_input_container {
    position: relative;
}
.adaptive_text_input {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 3px solid #aaaaaa;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #fff;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
}
.adaptive_text_input:focus {
    border-color: #00bafa;
}
.adaptive_text_input:focus + .adaptive_placeholder:before {
    color: #00bafa;
}
.adaptive_text_input:focus + .adaptive_placeholder:before, .adaptive_text_input:valid + .adaptive_placeholder:before {
    -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -16px) scale(0.9, 0.9);
}
.adaptive_text_input:invalid + .adaptive_placeholder:before {
    content: attr(alt);
}
.adaptive_text_input + .adaptive_placeholder {
    pointer-events: none;
    line-height: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
.adaptive_text_input + .adaptive_placeholder:before {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    content: attr(placeholder);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 2px;
    color: #898989;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally think about state in the other direction; instead of saying, "does this UI update count as a change in state," I think "does this UI update *require* a change in state in order to function." The answer is yes if:

1. I need to rely on some data in my `render` function to conditionally apply a certain class.
2. The fact that the UI looks one way or another (that is, that the UI is in a particular *state*) needs to be communicated to other parts of the application.

If the answer to both those questions are "no," I think it's perfectly valid to keep the UI changes purely in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Brandon says.

Consider this example:

At some point you might want certain operations (shortcut keys) to have different consequences based on what is focused. Then the focused object becomes part of your state.

If that NEVER happens, you could get away with a pure CSS solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @AndrewMedico. My answer speaks to 2 cases. One where the UI should be updated with react, the other, where CSS will suffice. It illustrates that there is no correct answer to the question. Brandon's answer is a general commentary on this, whereas mine has a concrete example. If it's not clear, I can elaborate.